# Prove that if a bijection $f:G\rightarrow H$ satisfies Property (1) then it satisfies Property (2).

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing

For property 1 we have that $f(g_1g_2)=f(g_1)  f(g_2).$ We are asked to prove that $f^{-1}(h_1h_2)=f^{-1}(h_1)f^{-1}(h_2).$ The question asks to prove that if a bijection $f:G\rightarrow H$ satisfies property 1, then it satisfies property 2.

My understanding of the problem is as follows:

since the function is bijective we have that $f(g_1) =h_1$, and $f(g_2)=h_2$ for $h_1,h_2\in H.$ But this says nothing about $f(g_1g_2)$.

I am confused as to what I should do with this, or if there is an easier way to go about this, any help is appreciated, I am not looking for a solution, just guidance on where to go.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable question, so why the downvote? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so $G$ and $H$ are groups, $f : G \rightarrow H$ is a bijection, and moreover we have $f(g_1 g_2) = f(g_1) f(g_2)$. The goal is to show that $f^{-1}(h_1h_2) = f^{-1}(h_1) f^{-1}(h_2)$ (that is, the inverse also is a homomorphism). The way we're going to do it as follows: the function is surjective, so $f(g_1) = h_1$ for some $g_1$ and $f(g_2) = h_2$ for some $g_2$. Now

$$ f^{-1}(h_1h_2) = f^{-1}(f(g_1)f(g_2)) = f^{-1}(f(g_1g_2)) = g_1g_2.$$

Since $f(g_1) = h_1$, we can take inverses to get $g_1 = f^{-1}(h_1)$. Same applies for $g_2$ and $h_2$. We have then

$$f^{-1}(h_1 h_2) = g_1 g_2 = f^{-1}(h_1) f^{-1}(h_2).$$

Comment: Question to ponder: did we use injectivity at any point? (Yes, but where?)